# \NewDocumentEnvironment eats the first non-letter token when used for verbatim environment

Tags: environments, verbatim, latex3, xparse

I was messing around with creating verbatim environment saving its contents to a file like the one described in [verbatim package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) documentation (end of section 2.2), but using `latex3` features. It worked fine initially until I've tried to add an optional argument. For some reason when it is not provided and the first token is not a letter then it is missing from the output.

After executing the following code using `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
% L3 interface for verbatim
\cs_new_eq:NN \verbatim_start: \verbatim@start
\cs_new:Nn \verbatim_set_processline:n {
    \cs_set:Nn \__func_temp:n {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \verbatim@processline {
        \__func_temp:n {\the\verbatim@line}
    }
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{verbexport}{O{export.tex}} {
    \group_begin:
    \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_char_special_seq {\char_set_catcode_other:N ##1}
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
    \verbatim_set_processline:n {
        \iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {##1}
    }
    \verbatim_start:
} {
    \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
    \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{verbexport}
\LaTeX a
\end{verbexport}
\begin{verbexport}[export2.tex]
\LaTeX a
\end{verbexport}
\end{document}
```

the contents of the `export.tex` file are

```
 a
```

while those of `export2.tex` are

```
\LaTeX a
```

My `latex` environment is

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-10>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class for examples of code. It's not meant for such usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to disable lookup of spaces before the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% L3 interface for verbatim
\cs_new_eq:NN \verbatim_start: \verbatim@start

\cs_new_protected:Nn \verbatim_set_processline:n
  {
    \cs_set_protected:Nn \__func_temp:n {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \verbatim@processline
      {
        \__func_temp:n {\the\verbatim@line}
      }
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{verbexport}{!O{export.tex}}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_char_special_seq {\char_set_catcode_other:N ##1}
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
    \verbatim_set_processline:n
      {
        \iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {##1}
      }
    \verbatim_start:
  }
  {
    \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
    \group_end:
  }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{verbexport}
\LaTeX a
\end{verbexport}
\begin{verbexport}[export2.tex]
\LaTeX a
\end{verbexport}
\end{document}
```

I changed something, in particular made `protected` the functions that do settings.

The content of both files will be

```
\LaTeX a
```